# Kasus des Relativpronomens im Relativsatz

Tags: sentence-structure, subordinate-clause, relative-clause, relative-pronoun

> "Du hast mir von einer Freundin erzählt.  Ist sie das?"

Ich möchte die obigen zwei Sätze verbinden.

> "Ist das die Freundin, von deren du mir erzählt hast?"

Ich habe etwas falsch geschrieben, aber ich kann keinen Fehler finden.  Bitte geben Sie mir eine Erklärung über die Grammatik der Relativsätze auf Deutsch und nicht auf Englisch.

Comment: Correct is: *Ist das die Freundin, von **der** du mir erzählt hast?*

Answer (score 6):

Es soll heißen "von der", und nicht von "deren". Das hat nichts mit Relativsätzen zu tun, sondern mit Kasus.

Answer (score 5):

Ich denke, dass ich den Fehler gefunden habe...

Nach dem Wort "von" benutzt man den Dativ, aber "deren" ist der Genitiv...